# Java Command Prompt Emulator

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a java program that commands through cmd.exe and prints their output. To do this, I'm using this code:

```
cmdLine = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe");
cmdLineOut = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cmdLine.getInputStream()));
cmdLineIn = new PrintWriter(cmdLine.getOutputStream());
// ...
cmdLineIn.println(command);
cmdLineIn.flush();
String s = null;
while ((s = cmdLineOut.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Although, when input is given, the output is never printed.

EDIT: Solved
The cmdLineOut.readLine() doesn't return null when the input is empty, it freezes. Since readLine freezes at the end no other code is executed, I just put the printing of the readLine in a seperate thread.

If somebody wants to answer this better, go ahead.

Comment: it could be using error output

Comment: If you want to execute a command that has no executable like `dir` you have to call `cmd.exe /c dir`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was doing at first, but after calling `cmd.exe /c cd path` then `cmd.exe /c dir` the directory isn't correct, so I need some way to maintain the environment.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually execute the user's command, at least in the snippet you posted. Also, nearly all command prompt "commands" are actually just programs that are on the default program search path. You should probably just `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(user_command)` for each command. This means that you will have to set up the input and output streams like you have already done for each command. You are right to get input in a separate thread, since attempting to read input will block the current thread until there is actually input to read.
However, some commands, even under UNIX or Linux systems, are "built-in" (like `cd`), meaning that the command prompt (aka "shell") handles the commands internally. Your program will have to test the user input to see if they are calling a built-in, and specially handle calls to built-in commands. Your program should actually be portable to non-Windows computers. Of course, the user would use different commands (`cp` instead of`copy`), but the only part you would have to add would be handling for other OS' shells' lists of built-ins (or simply have your program implement a "cross-platform" set of built-ins - this is your shell program, you get to make the rules).

Comment: Well the purpose of this is really to just accept input, send it to cmd, and send the output back to the client. The cmd that takes the command is on another computer, so I don't want a new shell, I just want a remote shell.

Comment: Ok then in that case, what you posted makes sense. Do you call System.out.flush() occasionally? flush() ensures that all the output in the buffer is actually written to standard output.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I was having a problem with the console not always showing all the output. I was debating whether to ask or not, but nevermind :D